# How to bring Local People Results in between Local SharePoint Results in SharePoint 2013 Everything Search Results Page?

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, display-templates

i have created the new query rule to bring the **People Search Results** to top of the **everything search results page**

I just Followed the below link to create the results like below.

[1. Sharepoint 2013 adding people to everything page](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.in/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-adding-people-to.html)
[image: SharePoint people to everything page]

But Actually i need the people results information in between the everything search results page.

Is this possible to get things done? 
Could you please help me regarding this i tried promoted by 5 in query rule but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What do you mean by "i need the people results information in between the everything search results page"

Comment: Yes @MatthewMcDermott, As of now people search results is showing at top in everything results page, but i  need  to show the  people results  after 3rd everything search results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the value showed on this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-AswWmGQqpC4/UUmq_CWGQZI/AAAAAAAABWM/Kn5K9vvp0Bg/s1600/6.png

to "This block is ranked within core results" ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this helps to you. But Try by changing the Sorting and Rank order in Query rule.

[Take a look on it](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/03/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

[Change settings for Search Results](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-settings-for-the-Search-Results-Web-Part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e).

Comment: I have followed the link, which you mentioned here but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I tried that in multiple scenario but not get positive results. @Naveen